# Density of adjoint operators

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras, topological-vector-spaces, ra.rings-and-algebras

I am interested in operators on a non-reflexive Banach space. Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $L(X)$ be the algebra of operators acting on $X$. We may embed $L(X)$ into $L(X^{\ast\ast})$ by $\Phi(T)=T^{\ast\ast}$; this is an algebra homomorphism. Is the image $\Phi(L(X))$ dense in $L(X^{**})$ in the sense of some of the classical operator topologies like WOT, SOT etc.?

Comment: Nice question, but why do you ask about the density of the embedding into `$L(X^{∗∗})$` instead of into `$L(X^∗)$`?

Comment: If `$X^*$` has the bounded approximation property, then the embedding of $L(X)$ into `$L(X^*)$` is strongly dense.  This is an immediate consequence of the principle of local reflexivity, which you can find in text books.  

Comment: Your original question has a negative answer for every non reflexive space. Just consider any operator in `$L(X^{**})$` that maps some point in $X$ to a point not in $X$.  There are plenty of rank one operators that do that. Operators in $\Phi(L(X))$ map $X$ into $X$.

Comment: Thank you, Professor. Just to clarify, *strongly* means in the sense of SOT?

Comment: Yes, SOT. Incidentally, in my comment about density of $L(X)$ in `$L(X^{*})$`, I was thinking about taking limits of uniformly bounded nets. If you really only care about SOT density, then no condition is needed.  Given $T$ in `$L(X^{*})$` and a finite dimensional subspace $F$ of `$X^{*}$`, choose a basis $(f_n)$ for $f$ and elements $(x_n)$ in $X$ s.t. $(x_n,f_n)$ is biorthogonal and consider `$S:=\sum_n x_n\otimes f_n$`. This finite rank operator is clearly weak`$^*$` continuous and agrees with $T$ on $F$.

Comment: That's interesting if it can be done any better than SOT. Are there any reasonable assumptions for $X$ to consider uniform limits?

Comment: Do you mean SOT limits but with the operators uniformly bounded?  That is what I meant. Uniform limits usually mean limits in the operator norm, so that density is equivalent to the reflexivity of $X$.  